# Add Entity to ChangeTracker manually

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an additional "strange" question about ChangeTracker in EF Core.
So, let's have an entity got externally. We know full information about it (with all possible includes and etc).
Is it possible to add this entity to ChangeTracker entity list for tracking it?

Thank you.

Comment: Might be as simple as this: `var entityEntry = context.Entry(receivedEntity);`

Comment: @KentKostelac I'll check soon, thank you!

Comment: check this [Attach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-6.0)